# building REST API - long header

Tags: php, apache, api

I'm building an API.. But I think my server sends a quite long header compared to other "APIs"..

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 30 Jun 2011 19:51:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze1
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=dv1nrjrd47qurff4u9tn8afa84; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Just want to know if there is any disadvantage of that regarding safety?

### edit

yay..! now I'm down to this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 30 Jun 2011 20:51:18 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no appreciable disadvantage in term of permormance to send these extra header to the client.
A client should never cache the response returned by a web service call since the client usually is not a browser.

You also start a session (see the PHPSESSID cookie) and if is not useful for the client, simple don't start the session

I usually tend to hide the version of apache and PHP for security reason.

Hide Apache version: ServerTokens PROD in the httpd.conf file

Hide PHP version: expose_php = Off in the php.ini

Restart Apache

Comment: how can I hide the version of apache and php?

Comment: when I add ServerToken PROD to httpd.conf I get an error when restarting apache:
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'ServerToken', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: Just written from scratch. The correct spelling is ServerTokens. You need to modify your current line and not add a new one